# Not able to execute ajax code in AEM 6.2 , getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to execute Ajax code in AEM 6.2 component but getting below error in console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )". 
When removing ajax code then on click Jquery is working and alert is showing "Insite Jquery function". and there is no error in console. But the moment i am adding Ajax code , the error is showing.

Please let me know what mistake i am dloing.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Insite Jquery function");
    $("#Shareitem").click(function(e){

        $.ajax((
            url: "/bin/runmodel",
            method: "GET",
            success: function() {
               alert("Inside Ajax");
            console.log("success");
            }
        ));

     });

});
</script>



<button type="button" id="Shareitem" name="Shareitem">Change Content</button>
```

Comment: use this  > $.ajax({
            url: "/bin/runmodel",
            method: "GET",
            success: function() {
               alert("Inside Ajax");
            console.log("success");
            }
        });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> $.ajax(( ... ));
> ```

An [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) is delimited with `{}` not `()`.